# Error unexpected token when using crypto-js with angular 5 project

Tags: angular, encryption, angular5, cryptojs

I need to encrypt data sent from angular-5 to php script and decrypt it in php then process it. I am new to these stuff.

Firstly, I installed the crypto-js lib:

`npm install --save crypto-js`

Then I imported it into `app.module.ts`:

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';
```

And added it to imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    crypto
```

Inside my `app.component.ts` file I am trying to encrypt a variable and test the result:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  this.crypto...
}
```

I've got an error on the `this.`:

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
>   expected.

Comment: Is crypto actually an Angular module? You can't just put arbitrary things in that list.

Comment: it was installed normally.

Comment: any other library to use it ?

Comment: What do you mean *"it was installed normally"*? By npm? That's nothing to do with Angular's modules. I'd suggest you read up on the DI in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're using symmetric encryption on the client side then the encryption key used is visible to the user/client. Which means anyone can decrypt anyone else's traffic. So what you are doing is pointless. You should be using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Rather importing * from crypto-js my team has simply put the crypto-js dependency in the scripts array in the .angular-cli.json.

Once you've done this at the top of the ts file you plan to use crypto you can add declare const CryptoJS; and then use it normally.

This method can also be used on any other non es6 or ts packaged dependency.

Comment: Thanks. Had this error: `Cannot read property 'ceil' of undefined` when using `CryptoJS.MD5` with `import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'` when moving from Angular 5.2 to Angular 6.x when trying to build with `"optimization": true,` in angular.json.
Have added : `"scripts": ["node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js" ]` in architect.build (yes you cannot add that into architect.serve, but it still work with ng serve) and `declare const CryptoJS;` and now it do not throw when using CryptoJS with `"optimization": true` !